# Android: a service to TTS displayed text

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am planning to write a service to enable Android users to listen to any text is currently displayed (be an email, an ebook, a web page, a note, an SMS, etc...), upon request.

Do you think it is feasible?
Do you know if it has been done, already?
How could I bind (a button? a gesture? something else?) a user input to the service activation?

I know these are quite generic questions, but I'm really on a pre-alpha stage for my project, I want to understand if it's feasible, to start with... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can use google translate service for doing your own tts, you need to do a httpConnection with the text that you need to listen

Comment: you can put a setting in your application where user can activate or not tts and you in function of that setting can do httpRequest to googletts

Comment: My question was more about the front-end, than the back-end (initially I am planning to use the internal TTS engine, "pico"...). I.e.: how do I get the text to be passed to TTS? Should I write specific code for each app I want to speech-enable (browser, clipboard, news-readers, ebook-readers, ...), or is there some kind of "screen text buffer" I can access? And, how to let user tell my service to activate itself?